# Codeigniter active record query where column contains json array

Tags: json, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I have a column which contain the following `[1,2,3...]` and `$myquery = array(1,2);`.

Normally I can write `this->db->where_in('column',$query);`

My thought was to run a for loop, then nest this to another for loop. 
But now I am stuck because it is a json array.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: how could i query the column, $this->db->where('column', query); the column contains json array, and query is php array